# Dynamic in-memory array declaration and assignment in 0.8.10

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to assign a dynamic in-memory array during the declaration? 
Like this:

```
uint[] memory someDynamicArr = [1,2,3];
```

Or the only possible way is:

```
uint[] memory someDynamicArr;
someDynamicArr[0] = 1;
someDynamicArr[1] = 2;
someDynamicArr[2] = 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/types.html#array-literals) fixed size memory arrays cannot be assigned to dynamically-sized memory arrays, i.e. the following is not possible:

```solidity
uint[] memory someDynamicArr = [1,2,3];
```

This will throw error because the type of `[1, 2, 3]` is `uint8[3] memory`, because the type of each of these constants is uint8. If you want the result to be a `uint[3] memory` type, you need to convert the first element to `uint`.

```solidity
uint[] memory someDynamicArr = [uint(1),2,3];
```

Following will throw an error too, because fixed size memory arrays cannot be assigned to dynamically-sized memory arrays.

```solidity
// uint[3] memory cannot be converted to uint[] memory.   
uint[] memory x = [uint(1), 3, 4];
```

If you want to initialize dynamically-sized arrays, you have to assign the individual elements:

```solidity
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract C {
    function f() public pure {
        uint[] memory x = new uint[](3);
        x[0] = 1;
        x[1] = 3;
        x[2] = 4;
    }
}
```